# Характеристики временных рядов

Tags: математика, matlab

Есть график временного ряда (синий). Я попытался дорисовать к нему ещё один, красный:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, по какой характеристике они здесь кардинально отличаются? Чтобы можно было сказать: "вот этот ряд сильно такой, а этот вот гораздо слабее". И желательно с функцией в MatLab, по которой можно сравнить. Я знаю только мат. ожидание и дисперсию, они вроде как одинаковые.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить об отсчётах, без анализа самой функции, то отличаются они частотой дискретизации.

Comment: Теоретически у них здесь может быть одинаковая частота дискретизации?

Comment: Теоретически - может. Если у красного графика значительно слабее выражены высокочастотные гармоники. Посмотрите ряды Фурье.

Comment: Подумал и решил, что скорее всего подойдёт сумма по модулю относительной разности между рядом и его скользящей средней с небольшим периодом. У синего ряда разности будут большие, у красного - маленькие.